# Quiz from external text file Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a quiz where I have questions and answers from an external text file to import into Python so that the user can input a selection.

The problem is that my code only prints `"Correct"` at the *end* of the quiz once, and doesn't say after each question answered if the user got the question correct or incorrect.

The first column (`detail[0]`) is where the question is and the correct answer is in the fourth column (`detail[4])`)

Thanks

Here is what is in the text file:

```
What is 1+1,1,2,2
What is 2+2,4,2,4
```

Here is the source code below:

```
def quiz():
    file = open("quiz.txt","r")
    right = False

    for line in file:
        detail = line.split(",")
        print(detail[0])
        select = input("Select 1 or 2: ")
        if select == detail[3]:
            right = True
            break

    if right == True:
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```

Comment: Well, you `break` out of the `for` loop when the first correct answer is given, so what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Also you only print "Correct" or "Incorrect" after the `for` loop is done, so only for the last question.

Comment: I had a similar code which has the break function so I tried using it, but obviously that's a problem, so I've removed it. Are there any suggestions you have to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the main `for-loop` to `print` the result there and then:

```
for line in file:
    detail = line.split(",")
    print(detail[0])
    select = input("Select 1 or 2: ")
    if select == detail[3]:
        print("correct!")
    else:
        print("incorrect :(")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it only works for the last question in the code, not sure why.

Comment: I think this is something to do with the format of the file, are the questions really after the third comma on every line? Take a look, I'm sure you can work it out or if you are stuck, post the file contents in the question

Comment: I have added it to my code, where the correct answer is always the last one in the file so that the correct answer is always detail[3]

Comment: Yeah I kept retrying and changing the position in the files to see if anything changes, but again, only work for the last question in the file. Thank you though